# Spring @Configuration Beans - 'Best' Location?

Tags: spring

Where is the 'best practice' place to put @Configuration beans in one's Spring project? It seems wrong putting config under `/src/main/java`, but otherwise the classes won't get compiled.

How do others approach this problem?

Comment: Why it is wrong? Those are just classes in the end...

Comment: They are, but they're config, and not what I'd consider the application proper. Perhaps I just have a skewed view of where they should belong!

Comment: (+1) @The Ohter Readers: "See the first comment below my answer, then you will understand the question: CITE "I was wanting to know specifically about @Configuration beans. Normally I'd expect configuration resources to lie in src/main/resources, but as `@Configuration` beans need to end up as compiled classes, this won't work. Is there a commonly-accepted place to put configuration elements that need to be compiled?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the only solution, if you want to decouple the configuration from the logic, is to add additional source folder to the Maven config:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/main/configuration</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

It seems that this solution will achieve what you want. `src/main/configuration` will be added to the compilation plugin and will end up in `target/classes` while, in the project source tree, those will be placed somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

`/src/main/java` is the root folder for the java source in maven project.
So it is the correct root folder.

But it is best practice to use packages in java project. -- Packages are mapped to directories.

So it is very common an best practice to have some package like`com.my_domain.my_application.service`
And this would correspond to the folder `/src/main/java/com/my_domain/my_application/service`

---

`@Configuration` annotated classes are java classes, and therfore they must be compiled.
In a default mavern project, only the files in `/src/main/java` and `/src/test/java`. If you want to seperate the `@Configuration` classes, then this is possible, but not in the `src/xxx/resource` folder.

The only thing you need to do, is to decalare an additional source direcory in maven with help of maven [build helper plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/).

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <source>add-source</source>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>${basedir}/src/main/javaconfig</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Now you hava a additional java source folder `/src/main/javaconfig` where you can put you `@Configuration` files. The content in this folder is merged with the one of `/src/main/java` before compiling. (After adding this to the pom, you need to instruct eclipse to update the project configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wanting to know specifically about @Configuration beans. Normally I'd expect configuration resources to lie in `src/main/resources`, but as @Configuration beans need to end up as compiled classes, this won't work. Is there a commonly-accepted place to put configuration elements that need to be compiled?

Comment: @Deejay: now I understand the question, have a look at my extended answer.